# layout problems with site

Tags: css, layout, width

I have a problem with my site. When I resize the window everything stays still and doesn't move, the window just crosses over everything.

Here are the images to epxlain it a bit better.. hopefully.

This is the site in normal window - http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/407/problem2a.jpg/

and when resized - http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/696/problemim.jpg/

Can anyone tell me what the problem is? I would like my layout to work like this website - http://www.thisoldbear.com/

Comment: I have a problem with my dishwasher. What is it? -- We will never know unless you tell us how you set up your current layout.

Comment: use your inspector (Firebug) to understand how http://www.thisoldbear.com/ works.

Comment: Why the cheek? I tried explaining it was fully as I could. What do you mean how I set it up?

Comment: I image you have some CSS code that defines a specific width for your main container.  Something like "width:900px" or something.  And it looks like the scroll bars have been turned off.  Look for "overflow-x: hidden" or something to that affect.  Other than those basic ideas, there's not much anyone can do to help without seeing your site and your code (or better, posting the bits of code that are causing the problem)

Comment: An analogy, not cheek sorry. By how is your current layout set up, I mean explain it to us: did you absolute position, table style, give a margin to the outer-most container? The more detail the better!

Comment: Yeah I have overflow-x hidden and a container at 1300px but I know this is really the best of ideas as it wont work on smaller devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next time, please add your HTML and CSS code to your question as it makes everything so much easier and you'll get more accurate answers.

By looking at your pics I get the feeling that you've added left side padding/margin (150px something?) to try and center your content, when you really should have added this to your container DIV(s)

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

This will center the content and keep it centered when you resize the window

**Update**

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <header>
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <nav>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
<div class="content">
  ...
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background: url(../../core/images/bg.png);
  font-family: 'Pontano Sans', sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: url(../../core/images/header.png);
}

#content, header {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 124px;
  height: 171px;
  background: url(../../core/images/logo.png);
}

nav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto 0px auto 150px;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #f4f4f4;
  outline: none;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 50px;
}
nav a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
```

Comment: When I added that everything jumbles up like the nvigation and logo :/

Comment: please post your HTML as well and I'll give you some pointers on how to restructure your mark-up

Comment: @user1506962 - I have no idea how your images are cut etc but see if the code I just posted works

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a big container with an 1000px width and used that to center your layout probably with margins and paddings.

Instead drop the big container and use just a single container with `margin: auto` to center it. Like this:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="main-container">
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#main-container {
    width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Note that you can not use `float:left` on the main container. If you need that (e.g. for background) include another container width `width:  100%` without padding or margin and float that one.

Comment: Yeah this worked but i'm guessing I need to change everything else seems everything has jumbled up?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the width you have assigned to your outermost layout (probably a div).
It seems like you have assigned a fixed width to your page which is about the same size or greater than your screen resolution size. Try using a lesser size with the properties margin:0 auto;